# Binding a Generic List of type struct to a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, repeater, generics

I've had a bit of a problem trying to bind a generic list to a repeater. The type used in the generic list is actually a struct.

I've built a basic example below:

```
struct Fruit
{
    public string FruitName;
    public string Price;    // string for simplicity.
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<Fruit> FruitList = new List<Fruit>();

    // create an apple and orange Fruit struct and add to List<Fruit>.
    Fruit apple = new Fruit();
    apple.FruitName = "Apple";
    apple.Price = "3.99";
    FruitList.Add(apple);

    Fruit orange = new Fruit();
    orange.FruitName = "Orange";
    orange.Price = "5.99";
    FruitList.Add(orange);


    // now bind the List to the repeater:
    repFruit.DataSource = FruitList;
    repFruit.DataBind();

}
```

I have a simple struct to model Fruit, we have two properties which are FruitName and Price. I start by creating an empty generic list of type 'FruitList'.

I then create two fruits using the struct (apple and orange). These fruits are then added to the list.

Finally, I bind the generic list to the DataSource property of the repeater...

The markup looks like this:

```
<asp:repeater ID="repFruit" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    Name: <%# Eval("FruitName") %><br />
    Price: <%# Eval("Price") %><br />
    <hr />
</ItemTemplate>
```

I expect to see the fruit name and price printed on the screen, separated by a horizontal rule.

At the moment I am getting an error relating to actual binding...

```
**Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: '_Default+Fruit' does not contain a property with the name 'FruitName'.**
```

I'm not even sure if this can work? Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Random note, the ListView class is massively supersedes the repeater in terms of capability.

Comment: @Chris Marisic thank you for the tip, I am reading about the ListView now, looks really good: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change your public field into a public property.

Change this: `public string FruitName;`

To:

```
public string FruitName { get; set; }
```

Otherwise you could make fruitName private and include a public property for it.

```
private string fruitName;

public string FruitName { get { return fruitName; } set { fruitName = value; } }
```

[Here is a link with someone who has had the same issue as you.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1458854.aspx)

Comment: It worked! God I feel soo stupid now, makes a lot of sense, thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Error tells you everything you need to know. You have public fields not properties defined for  FruitName and Price.