# Displaying collection in Repeater control

Tags: asp.net, exception, repeater

I'm beginner in Asp.Net and Im trying to display "gc" on reapet control.

Here's the code-behind:

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
      List<GlassesCollection> gc= BL.Example.GetCategory() ;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rpt1.DataSource = gc;
        rpt1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void rpt1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Im using the following ASP code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("gc") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But in run time i get this Exception: 
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'ISeeOptic.DataType.GlassesCollection' does not contain a property with the name 'gc'.

Why i get this Excption and idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What properties does `GlassesCollection` expose? Those are the ones you can `Eval` against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try eval the specific property rather than the object

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>         
      <%# Eval("gcProperty") %>     
   </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

The [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525660/binding-a-generic-list-of-type-struct-to-a-repeater) gives more details about binding a repeater to a generic list.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally take advantage of DataBinder class which has the most power and flexibility the same as code listing here...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>         
      <%# DataBinder.Eval("gcProperty") %>     
   </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: In the context of binding to a row in a repeater - is there any difference between Eval and DataBinder.Eval. This links says not http://forums.asp.net/p/984156/1264782.aspx. What is the difference other than scope - what extra would it give. I'm honestly curious